# Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: php, mysql, sql, exception

I have the following PHP Validation:

Assuming the POST variables are set in the form as expected.

```
 // Check if email input field is empty     
 if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
        $emailErr = "Email address required";
    }
    else {
    // If it is not empty, quote to prevent SQL injection and assign it to a variable
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $safe_email = $db->quote($_POST['email']);
    }

    // same for password, but instead of quote I hash the password below
    if (empty($_POST["password"])) {
        $passwordErr = "Password required";
    }
    else {
        $password = $_POST["password"];
    }
```

If there are no errors:
    // hash the password
    $hashed_password = md5($password);

```
// create an insert query, insert safe email and hashed password into database
$query = "INSERT INTO user VALUES ('', 0, '$safe_email', '$hashed_password')";

// perform the above query
$result = $db->query($query);
```

The problem I am having is when I use `$safe_email` instead of just `$email` in the query it gives me this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
>   'leomessi@adidas.com'', 'ce0a8ad8a758c3d242d9e050c4707fb6')' at line
>   1' in C:\wamp\www\Coursework\register.php on line 65

Not quite sure what the problem is here as my syntax seems to be fine.

Here is my db structure:

[image]

Comment: `'leomessi@adidas.com''` seems that not properly quoted string

Comment: I'm fairly sure that db->quote adds the required quotes, and you're putting the result inside extra quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already added the quotes with `$db->quote()` so you need to remove them from `$query`.
Visit https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php#112169 and check the code in the example.